# What in JavaScript can make both contentEditable and textarea unable to recieve any input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What could make both contentEditable and textarea not clickable per say? I set up content editable in file A, and it worked fine. I was trying to insert the following code from file A to my file B:

```
<script>
        function storeUsernote(id) {
          var note = document.getElementById('note').innerHTML;
          localStorage.setItem('usernote',note);
        }

        function getUsernote() {
          if ( localStorage.getItem('usernote')) {
            var note = localStorage.getItem('usernote');
          }
          else {
            var note = 'Write your note here';
          }
          document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = note;
        }

        function clearLocal() {
          clear: localStorage.clear();
          return false;
        }
    </script>


        <div id="oneout" style="scoped">

            <div id="oneout_inner">
                <div id="note-pad">
                    <div id="note" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUsernote(this.id);"></div>
                </div>
                <center>
                    <a class="clear" href='' onclick='javascript:clearLocal();'>Clear</a>
                </center>
                <script>
                  getUsernote();
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

literally at the end of of my /html tag. When I tried to put it inside the html tag, it only updated to changes I made to the content-editable area in file A. But when I put it outside my /html tag, it would be able to use the "clear" function and reset the data from file B, and it would affect file A as well. Finally, when i changed my initial style declaration to:

```
<style scoped>
html,body {
margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #FFF;
font-family: "Liberation Sans", "Dejavu Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma; font-size: 10pt;
}
#perspective {
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
background: transparent;
}
#preset {
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 48px;
text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 48px;
background: #000; color: #FFF; display: none; z-index: 1000;
}
a:link {
color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; opacity: 0.7;
min-width: 150px; margin-left: 0px;
transition: 0.2s ease-in; display: inline-block;
cursor: default; /* (pointer|default) */
} 
a:hover {
color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; opacity: 1.0;
min-width: 155px; margin-left: -5px; /* (-5px|5px) link move left or right */
transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
a:active  { color: #FFF; }
a:visited { color: #FFF; }
input[type="text"] {
width: 20px; border: 0;
opacity: 0.8; border-radius: 1px;
margin: 1px; padding: 2px 2px; transition: 0.3s ease;
cursor: default; /* (pointer|default) */
}
input[type="text"]:hover { width: 30px; }
input[type="text"]:focus { width: 150px; opacity: 1.0; transition: 0.3s ease; cursor: text; }
*:focus                  { outline: none; }
.container {
position: fixed; top: 30%; left: 50%; width: 150px; height: auto;
margin-left: -75px; margin-top: -20px; /* Vertical Align */
overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap;
transition: 1s ease; /* Animation speed/time */ 
}
.container label {
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
display: block; font-weight: bold; 
}
/*#box-3 { margin-left: -75px; opacity: 1; }*/ /* Selected box */
#search td:nth-child(1)     { text-align: right; }
#search label               { border: 0; font-weight: normal; opacity: 0.8; padding-right: 10px; }
#switch {
position: fixed; bottom: 10%; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 16px;
margin-left: 0px; cursor: default;
opacity: 0.7; transition: 0.3s ease-in;
text-align: center; visibility: hidden;
}
#switch:hover { opacity: 1.0; transition: 0.3s ease-out; }
.switch {
display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px;
border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 10px;
background: transparent; transition: 0.3s ease-in;
cursor: default; /* (pointer|default) */
}
#shadow-top {
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 5px; margin-top: -5px;
background: #000; box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000; opacity: 0.5;
}
#shadow-bot {
position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 5px; margin-bottom: -5px;
background: #000; box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000;opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

the whole page broke, *but* the contenteditable section worked. I can't post the several hundred lines of javaScript I have at play. I tried to make only the content editable section follow a style scoped, but that didn't work either (no change). Any suggestions, at least in general (i.e some variable was set to false, conflicting priorities, etc) that may explain the problem?

**Edit**: The following code snippet reproduces the problem

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};


// + ------------------------------------ Settings (JS) - BEGIN ------------------------------------ +

var presets = [ // curve x3(x2), margins x3(x2), translateZ x3(x2), rotation x3(x7), dim x3
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -1050, 350, 700, 1050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, -30, 0, 0, -60, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 1
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, -45, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 2
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -1050, 350, 700, 1050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -45, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -130, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 3
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -179, 0, 0, -179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 4
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 5
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -330, -650, -920, 330, 650, 920, 30, 160, 280, 30, 160, 280, 0, 20, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, -20, 0, 0, -40, 0, 0, -60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 6
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 45, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, -45, -45, 0, -135, -135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 7
];
var preset = 2; // 0 = null (Custom settings) (1,3 and 6 is widescreen)
var displayPreset = false; // Output current settings as preset string

// * = loaded from preset
var pg = 3; // Selected box
var searchBox = 3; // Box containing search engines/input fields (see "links")
var dim = [25, 0, 0]; // * Opacity: 0-100 (step1,step2,step3) (%)
var dimColor = "#524c59"; // Text input dim color
var background = "#14101c"; // Background color
var color = "#d6ccdc"; // Text/Link color
var autoFocus = "" // "" = none | default: "search-1"

var enableScroll = true; // Enable/Disable the posibility to scroll boxes
var enableTags = true; // Show/Hide switch buttons/tags
var enableKeys = true; // Allow key navigation when search field is not active
var enableTouch = true; // Enable touch screen support
var enableTitle = false; // Enable clickable box titles/content

var invertScroll = false; // Invert mouse wheel
var useScrollLock = true; // Delay next scroll trigger (prevents box skip)
var scrollLockMS = 25; // Wait in milliseconds
var edgeBlock = true; // Block scrolling past the edge

var curve = [ // Vertical movement (marginTop)
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var margins = [ // Horizontal movment (MarginLeft)
  [-350, -700, -700], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [350, 700, 700] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var marginT = -20; // Default marginTop
var marginC = -75; // Default marginLeft (center)

var translateZ = [ // Depth movement (z-index)
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var perspective = 800;

var rotation = [ // [ X, Y, Z] Degree (angle)
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0], // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Center/Default
];

var waifu = [ // "./waifu-left.png", "./waifu-right.png" ("" = none)
  "", ""
];

var boxSetup = [ // Format: ["Title", "#color"],
  ["News", "#d99395"], // box-1
  ["Social", "#c4d1a1"], // box-2
  ["Search", "#9bb6d4"], // box-3
  ["Entertainment", "#db9cbe"], // box-4
  ["Utility", "#d1c894"], // box-5
];

// Link setup (separate with "---", "---" (must not exceed boxSetup))
// Format: ["Name", "URL"],
var links = [
  // News -           box-1
  ["Russia Today", "http://rt.com/"],
  ["Reuters", "http://www.reuters.com/"],
  ["Al Jazeera", "http://america.aljazeera.com/"],
  ["The Raw Story", "http://rawstory.com/"],
  ["Liveleak", "http://www.liveleak.com/"],
  ["Briebart", "http://www.breitbart.com/"],
  ["The Daily Beast", "http://www.thedailybeast.com/"],
  ["Ars Technica", "http://arstechnica.com/"],
  ["Recode", "http://recode.net/"],
  ["Engadget", "http://www.engadget.com/"],
  ["Gizmodo", "http://gizmodo.com/"],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Social -          box-2
  ["Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/"],
  ["Reddit", "http://www.reddit.com/"],
  ["Deviantart", "http://www.deviantart.com/"],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Search -         box-3
  ["Duck Duck Go", "https://duckduckgo.com/?q="],
  ["Bing Images", "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q="],
  ["YouTube", "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="],
  ["Wikipedia", "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="],
  ["IMDb", "http://www.imdb.com/find?q="],
  ["Urban Dictionary", "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term="],
  ["Amazon", "http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Entertainment -  box-4
  ["Netflix", "http://www.netflix.com"],
  ["Project Free TV", "http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/"],
  ["YouTube", "http://youtube.com"],
  ["Solar Movie", "http://www.solarmovie.tl/"],
  ["That Guy With The Glasses", "http://thatguywiththeglasses.com/"],
  ["StumbleUpon", "http://stumbleupon.com"],
  ["The Onion", "http://www.theonion.com/"],
  ["What Should I Read Next", "http://whatshouldireadnext.com/"],
  ["Which Book", "http://www.openingthebook.com/whichbook/"],
  ["TechRaptor", "http://techraptor.net/"],
  ["TechCrunch", "http://techcrunch.com/"],
  ["Gamer Headlines", "http://www.gamerheadlines.com/"],
  ["ShackNews", "http://www.shacknews.com/"],


  ["---", "---"],

  // Utility -          box-5
  ["Wolfram Alpha", "http://www.wolframalpha.com/"],
  ["Mobilism", "http://forum.mobilism.org/index.php"],
  ["Desmos Calculator", "https://www.desmos.com/calculator"],
  ["Mathway", "https://www.mathway.com/"],
  ["Gmail", "http://gmail.com"],
  ["Wallhaven", "http://alpha.wallhaven.cc/"],
  ["The Paper Wall", "http://www.thepaperwall.com/index.php"],
  ["Guerrilla Mail", "https://www.guerrillamail.com/"],
  ["Kickass Torrents", "https://kickass.to/"],
  ["Tinypic", "http://tinypic.com/"],
  ["Recipies", "http://ck.booru.org/"],
  ["Tineye", "https://www.tineye.com/"],
  ["File Dropper", "http://www.filedropper.com/"],
  ["Paste2", "http://paste2.org/"],

];

// + ------------------------------------- Settings (JS) - END ------------------------------------- +


function init() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style.background = background;
  body.style.color = color;

  if (preset > 0) { // load preset
    var p = preset - 1;

    var e = 0,
      f = 0,
      g = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {
      switch (e) {
        case 0:
          curve[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
        case 1:
          margins[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
        case 2:
          translateZ[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
      }

      f++;
      if (f >= 3) {
        f = 0;
        if (g == 0) {
          g = 1;
        } else {
          g = 0;
          e++;
        }
      }
    }

    var a = 0,
      b = 0;
    for (var i = 18; i <= 38; i++) {
      rotation[a][b] = presets[p][i];
      b++;
      if (b >= 3) {
        b = 0;
        a++;
      }
    }

    var d = 39;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      dim[i] = presets[p][d];
      d++;
    }
  }

  $('perspective').style.perspective = perspective + "px";

  if (body.addEventListener) {
    body.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  } else {
    body.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
  }

  clear();
  build();

  var linkTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var a = 0; a < linkTags.length; a++) {
    linkTags[a].style.color = color;
  }

  var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
    inputTags[i].style.color = background;
  }

  var switchClass = document.getElementsByClassName('switch');
  for (var c = 0; c < switchClass.length; c++) {
    switchClass[c].style.borderColor = color;
  }

  if (enableTags) {
    $('switch').style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  cleanup();

  if (autoFocus.length > 0) {
    $(autoFocus).focus();
  }

  if (displayPreset) { // generate and display preset
    var genPreset = "[" + curve[0][0] + "," + curve[0][1] + "," + curve[0][2] + ", " + curve[1][0] + "," + curve[1][1] + "," + curve[1][2] + ", \
" + margins[0][0] + "," + margins[0][1] + "," + margins[0][2] + ", " + margins[1][0] + "," + margins[1][1] + "," + margins[1][2] + ", \
" + translateZ[0][0] + "," + translateZ[0][1] + "," + translateZ[0][2] + ", " + translateZ[1][0] + "," + translateZ[1][1] + "," + translateZ[1][2] + ", ";

    var a = 0;
    b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
      genPreset += rotation[a][b];

      if (b >= 2) {
        b = 0;
        a++;
        if (a < rotation.length) {
          genPreset += " ,";
        }
      } else {
        b++;
        genPreset += ",";
      }
    }
    genPreset += "],";

    //prompt("Animation preset : ",genPreset);
    $('preset').innerHTML = "Animation preset : " + genPreset;
    $('preset').style.display = "block";
  }
}

function clear() {
  $('boxes').innerHTML = "";
  $('switch').innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i <= boxSetup.length - 1; i++) {
    $('boxes').innerHTML += "<div id='box-" + (i + 1) + "' class='container'></div>\n";
    $('switch').innerHTML += "<div id='pg-" + (i + 1) + "' class='switch' onclick='javascript:go(" + (i + 1) + ");'></div> \n";

    var onclick;
    if (enableTitle) {
      onclick = "javascript:go(" + (i + 1) + ");";
    } else {
      onclick = "";
    }

    if ((i + 1) == searchBox) {
      $('box-' + searchBox).innerHTML = "<label style='color: " + boxSetup[(searchBox - 1)][1] + "; \
" + "border-color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + ";' onclick='" + onclick + "'>" + boxSetup[i][0] + "</label></br />\
" + "<table id='search' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>\
" + "<tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>\n";
    } else {
      $('box-' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<label style='color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + "; \
" + "border-color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + ";' onclick='" + onclick + "'>" + boxSetup[i][0] + "</label></br />\n";
    }
  }

  if (waifu[0] != "") {
    $('waifu-left').style.display = "block";
    $('waifu-left').src = waifu[0];
  }
  if (waifu[1] != "") {
    $('waifu-right').style.display = "block";
    $('waifu-right').src = waifu[1];
  }
}

function build() {
  var skip = false,
    c = 1,
    r = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i <= links.length - 1; i++) {
    if (links[i][0] == "---" && links[i][1] == "---") {
      skip = true;
      c++;
    }

    if (!skip) {
      if (c == searchBox) {
        // search engines
        var table = $('search');
        var row = table.insertRow(r);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
          cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        cell1.innerHTML = "<label for='search-" + r + "'>" + links[i][0] + "</label>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input id='search-" + r + "' type='text' value='' \
" + "onfocus='javascript:activeInput=true;if(searchBox!=pg) go(searchBox);' onblur='javascript:activeInput=false;' \
" + "onkeypress='javascript:handleKeyPress(event,\"" + links[i][1] + "\",this.value);' />";

        r++;
      } else {
        // links
        var lnk_js = ["", ""];
        if (enableTitle) {
          lnk_js = ["javascript:open(\"", "\");"];
        }
        $('box-' + c).innerHTML += "<a href='" + lnk_js[0] + links[i][1] + lnk_js[1] + "' target='_self'>" + links[i][0] + "</a><br />";
      }
    }

    skip = false;
  }
}

function cleanup() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (pg == searchBox) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++) {
      input[i].style.background = color;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++) {
      input[i].style.background = dimColor;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= boxSetup.length; i++) {
    $('pg-' + i).style.background = "transparent";
  }
  $('pg-' + pg).style.background = color;

  var b = 0,
    c = 0,
    steps = parseInt(rotation.length / 2);
  if (pg >= 2) { // left side
    for (var i = (pg - 1); i >= 1; i--) {
      $('box-' + i).style.cssText = "opacity: " + (parseFloat(dim[c] / 100)) + "; \
" + "margin-left: " + (margins[0][c] + marginC) + "px; margin-top: " + (curve[0][c] + marginT) + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg);";

      if (c < steps - 1) {
        c++;
        b++;
      }
    }
  }

  b = steps;
  c = 0;
  if (pg <= boxSetup.length) { // right side
    for (var i = (pg + 1); i <= boxSetup.length; i++) {
      $('box-' + i).style.cssText = "opacity: " + (parseFloat(dim[c] / 100)) + "; \
" + "margin-left: " + (margins[1][c] + marginC) + "px; margin-top: " + (curve[1][c] + marginT) + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[1][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg);";

      if (c < steps - 1) {
        c++;
        b++;
      }
    }
  }
}

function move(p) {
  var c = rotation.length - 1;

  $('box-' + pg).style.cssText = "opacity: 1.0; \
" + "margin-left: " + marginC + "px; margin-top: " + marginT + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(0px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[c][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[c][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[c][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(0px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[c][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[c][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[c][0] + "deg);";

  cleanup();
}

function go(x) { // switch using tags
  if (x != pg) {
    if (x > pg)
      while (x > pg) {
        move(pg++);
      } else
        while (x < pg) {
          move(pg--);
        }
  }
}

function open(url) { // url handler w/ clickable boxes
  var x = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if ((links[i][1] == url && x == pg) || !enableTitle) {
      window.location = url;
    } else if (links[i][1] == url) {
      go(x);
    }

    if (links[i][0] == "---" && links[i][1] == "---") {
      x++;
    }
  }
}

function handleKeyPress(e, url, q) { // query
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which
  if (key == 13) {
    window.location = url + q;
  }
}

var scrollLock = false,
  sl_timer;

function MouseWheelHandler(e) { // scroll navigation
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

  if ((!scrollLock || !useScrollLock) && enableScroll) {
    if (!invertScroll) {
      if (delta == -1 && pg < boxSetup.length) {
        move(pg++);
      } else if (delta == -1 && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
        go(1);
      }
      if (delta == 1 && pg > 1) {
        move(pg--);
      } else if (delta == 1 && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
        go(boxSetup.length);
      }
    } else {
      if (delta == 1 && pg < boxSetup.length) {
        move(pg++);
      } else if (delta == 1 && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
        go(1);
      }
      if (delta == -1 && pg > 1) {
        move(pg--);
      } else if (delta == -1 && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
        go(boxSetup.length);
      }
    }

    if (useScrollLock) {
      scrollLock = true;
      clearTimeout(sl_timer);
      sl_timer = setTimeout("scrollLock=false", scrollLockMS);
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var activeInput = false;
document.onkeydown = function(e) { // key navigation
  if (!activeInput && enableKeys) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which

    if (key >= 49 && (key <= 57 && key <= (48 + boxSetup.length))) {
      go(key - 48);
    } // key 1-9
    if (key >= 97 && (key <= 105 && key <= (96 + boxSetup.length))) {
      go(key - 96);
    } // num key 1-9

    if ((key == 37 || key == 65) && pg > 1) {
      move(pg--);
    } // key left and A
    else if ((key == 37 || key == 65) && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
      go(boxSetup.length);
    }
    if ((key == 39 || key == 68) && pg < boxSetup.length) {
      move(pg++);
    } // key right and D
    else if ((key == 39 || key == 68) && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
      go(1);
    }
  }
}

function getUsernote() {
  document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = 'Write your note here';
}

getUsernote();
init();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Liberation Sans", "Dejavu Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
#perspective {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
#preset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
a:link {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1.0;
  min-width: 155px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  /* (-5px|5px) link move left or right */
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
a:active {
  color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
input[type="text"]:hover {
  width: 30px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: text;
}
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  /* Vertical Align */
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 1s ease;
  /* Animation speed/time */
}
.container label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*#box-3 { margin-left: -75px; opacity: 1; }*/

/* Selected box */

#search td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
#search label {
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#switch {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#switch:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
#shadow-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#shadow-bot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
  <div id="boxes"></div>
</div>
<div id="switch"></div>

<div id="preset"></div>

<div id="oneout" style="scoped">
  <div id="oneout_inner">
    <div id="note-pad">
      <div id="note" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <center>
      <a class="clear" href=''>Clear</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you show us the 'lots of code' in the css? There is one thing that could get affected, called 'user-select'

Comment: @towc alright, I've updated the css to include all of it

Comment: still can't see the css

Comment: fixed for the second time, sorry about that, it went in formatted wrong

Comment: and this is all of the html? Some stuff in the js isn't linked to anything. Mind putting a fiddle with everything and one only with the stuff needed to demonstrate?

Comment: @towc oh no, that's not all the html. It's just the parts that seemed relevant. I can't really make one with the stuff needed to demonstrate because, well, I think everything is needed more or less. The other jfiddle with everything is here, formatted the same way I see my file (no separate stylesheet or external scripts): http://jsfiddle.net/2t76Lzps/1/

The problem is in the top left corner: I can't enter anything into that area that says "write your note here". On my local computer, I can change the text in that area from file A and reset it in file B (shown in the fiddle).

Comment: Some notes: don't use inline event listeners. Don't include code after closing `</body>` nor `</html>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `#perspective` is above (in z-axis) your contenteditable element.

You can solve it adding

```css
#oneout {
    position: relative;
}
```

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};


// + ------------------------------------ Settings (JS) - BEGIN ------------------------------------ +

var presets = [ // curve x3(x2), margins x3(x2), translateZ x3(x2), rotation x3(x7), dim x3
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -1050, 350, 700, 1050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, -30, 0, 0, -60, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 1
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, -45, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 2
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -1050, 350, 700, 1050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -45, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -130, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 3
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -179, 0, 0, -179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 4
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 5
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -330, -650, -920, 330, 650, 920, 30, 160, 280, 30, 160, 280, 0, 20, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, -20, 0, 0, -40, 0, 0, -60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0], // Preset 6
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -350, -700, -700, 350, 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 45, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, -45, -45, 0, -135, -135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0], // Preset 7
];
var preset = 2; // 0 = null (Custom settings) (1,3 and 6 is widescreen)
var displayPreset = false; // Output current settings as preset string

// * = loaded from preset
var pg = 3; // Selected box
var searchBox = 3; // Box containing search engines/input fields (see "links")
var dim = [25, 0, 0]; // * Opacity: 0-100 (step1,step2,step3) (%)
var dimColor = "#524c59"; // Text input dim color
var background = "#14101c"; // Background color
var color = "#d6ccdc"; // Text/Link color
var autoFocus = "" // "" = none | default: "search-1"

var enableScroll = true; // Enable/Disable the posibility to scroll boxes
var enableTags = true; // Show/Hide switch buttons/tags
var enableKeys = true; // Allow key navigation when search field is not active
var enableTouch = true; // Enable touch screen support
var enableTitle = false; // Enable clickable box titles/content

var invertScroll = false; // Invert mouse wheel
var useScrollLock = true; // Delay next scroll trigger (prevents box skip)
var scrollLockMS = 25; // Wait in milliseconds
var edgeBlock = true; // Block scrolling past the edge

var curve = [ // Vertical movement (marginTop)
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var margins = [ // Horizontal movment (MarginLeft)
  [-350, -700, -700], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [350, 700, 700] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var marginT = -20; // Default marginTop
var marginC = -75; // Default marginLeft (center)

var translateZ = [ // Depth movement (z-index)
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
];
var perspective = 800;

var rotation = [ // [ X, Y, Z] Degree (angle)
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0], // * Left side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0], // * Right side (step1,step2,step3)
  [0, 0, 0] // * Center/Default
];

var waifu = [ // "./waifu-left.png", "./waifu-right.png" ("" = none)
  "", ""
];

var boxSetup = [ // Format: ["Title", "#color"],
  ["News", "#d99395"], // box-1
  ["Social", "#c4d1a1"], // box-2
  ["Search", "#9bb6d4"], // box-3
  ["Entertainment", "#db9cbe"], // box-4
  ["Utility", "#d1c894"], // box-5
];

// Link setup (separate with "---", "---" (must not exceed boxSetup))
// Format: ["Name", "URL"],
var links = [
  // News -           box-1
  ["Russia Today", "http://rt.com/"],
  ["Reuters", "http://www.reuters.com/"],
  ["Al Jazeera", "http://america.aljazeera.com/"],
  ["The Raw Story", "http://rawstory.com/"],
  ["Liveleak", "http://www.liveleak.com/"],
  ["Briebart", "http://www.breitbart.com/"],
  ["The Daily Beast", "http://www.thedailybeast.com/"],
  ["Ars Technica", "http://arstechnica.com/"],
  ["Recode", "http://recode.net/"],
  ["Engadget", "http://www.engadget.com/"],
  ["Gizmodo", "http://gizmodo.com/"],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Social -          box-2
  ["Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/"],
  ["Reddit", "http://www.reddit.com/"],
  ["Deviantart", "http://www.deviantart.com/"],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Search -         box-3
  ["Duck Duck Go", "https://duckduckgo.com/?q="],
  ["Bing Images", "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q="],
  ["YouTube", "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="],
  ["Wikipedia", "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="],
  ["IMDb", "http://www.imdb.com/find?q="],
  ["Urban Dictionary", "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term="],
  ["Amazon", "http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="],

  ["---", "---"],

  // Entertainment -  box-4
  ["Netflix", "http://www.netflix.com"],
  ["Project Free TV", "http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/"],
  ["YouTube", "http://youtube.com"],
  ["Solar Movie", "http://www.solarmovie.tl/"],
  ["That Guy With The Glasses", "http://thatguywiththeglasses.com/"],
  ["StumbleUpon", "http://stumbleupon.com"],
  ["The Onion", "http://www.theonion.com/"],
  ["What Should I Read Next", "http://whatshouldireadnext.com/"],
  ["Which Book", "http://www.openingthebook.com/whichbook/"],
  ["TechRaptor", "http://techraptor.net/"],
  ["TechCrunch", "http://techcrunch.com/"],
  ["Gamer Headlines", "http://www.gamerheadlines.com/"],
  ["ShackNews", "http://www.shacknews.com/"],


  ["---", "---"],

  // Utility -          box-5
  ["Wolfram Alpha", "http://www.wolframalpha.com/"],
  ["Mobilism", "http://forum.mobilism.org/index.php"],
  ["Desmos Calculator", "https://www.desmos.com/calculator"],
  ["Mathway", "https://www.mathway.com/"],
  ["Gmail", "http://gmail.com"],
  ["Wallhaven", "http://alpha.wallhaven.cc/"],
  ["The Paper Wall", "http://www.thepaperwall.com/index.php"],
  ["Guerrilla Mail", "https://www.guerrillamail.com/"],
  ["Kickass Torrents", "https://kickass.to/"],
  ["Tinypic", "http://tinypic.com/"],
  ["Recipies", "http://ck.booru.org/"],
  ["Tineye", "https://www.tineye.com/"],
  ["File Dropper", "http://www.filedropper.com/"],
  ["Paste2", "http://paste2.org/"],

];

// + ------------------------------------- Settings (JS) - END ------------------------------------- +


function init() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style.background = background;
  body.style.color = color;

  if (preset > 0) { // load preset
    var p = preset - 1;

    var e = 0,
      f = 0,
      g = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {
      switch (e) {
        case 0:
          curve[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
        case 1:
          margins[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
        case 2:
          translateZ[g][f] = presets[p][i];
          break;
      }

      f++;
      if (f >= 3) {
        f = 0;
        if (g == 0) {
          g = 1;
        } else {
          g = 0;
          e++;
        }
      }
    }

    var a = 0,
      b = 0;
    for (var i = 18; i <= 38; i++) {
      rotation[a][b] = presets[p][i];
      b++;
      if (b >= 3) {
        b = 0;
        a++;
      }
    }

    var d = 39;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      dim[i] = presets[p][d];
      d++;
    }
  }

  $('perspective').style.perspective = perspective + "px";

  if (body.addEventListener) {
    body.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  } else {
    body.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
  }

  clear();
  build();

  var linkTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var a = 0; a < linkTags.length; a++) {
    linkTags[a].style.color = color;
  }

  var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
    inputTags[i].style.color = background;
  }

  var switchClass = document.getElementsByClassName('switch');
  for (var c = 0; c < switchClass.length; c++) {
    switchClass[c].style.borderColor = color;
  }

  if (enableTags) {
    $('switch').style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  cleanup();

  if (autoFocus.length > 0) {
    $(autoFocus).focus();
  }

  if (displayPreset) { // generate and display preset
    var genPreset = "[" + curve[0][0] + "," + curve[0][1] + "," + curve[0][2] + ", " + curve[1][0] + "," + curve[1][1] + "," + curve[1][2] + ", \
" + margins[0][0] + "," + margins[0][1] + "," + margins[0][2] + ", " + margins[1][0] + "," + margins[1][1] + "," + margins[1][2] + ", \
" + translateZ[0][0] + "," + translateZ[0][1] + "," + translateZ[0][2] + ", " + translateZ[1][0] + "," + translateZ[1][1] + "," + translateZ[1][2] + ", ";

    var a = 0;
    b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
      genPreset += rotation[a][b];

      if (b >= 2) {
        b = 0;
        a++;
        if (a < rotation.length) {
          genPreset += " ,";
        }
      } else {
        b++;
        genPreset += ",";
      }
    }
    genPreset += "],";

    //prompt("Animation preset : ",genPreset);
    $('preset').innerHTML = "Animation preset : " + genPreset;
    $('preset').style.display = "block";
  }
}

function clear() {
  $('boxes').innerHTML = "";
  $('switch').innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i <= boxSetup.length - 1; i++) {
    $('boxes').innerHTML += "<div id='box-" + (i + 1) + "' class='container'></div>\n";
    $('switch').innerHTML += "<div id='pg-" + (i + 1) + "' class='switch' onclick='javascript:go(" + (i + 1) + ");'></div> \n";

    var onclick;
    if (enableTitle) {
      onclick = "javascript:go(" + (i + 1) + ");";
    } else {
      onclick = "";
    }

    if ((i + 1) == searchBox) {
      $('box-' + searchBox).innerHTML = "<label style='color: " + boxSetup[(searchBox - 1)][1] + "; \
" + "border-color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + ";' onclick='" + onclick + "'>" + boxSetup[i][0] + "</label></br />\
" + "<table id='search' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>\
" + "<tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>\n";
    } else {
      $('box-' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<label style='color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + "; \
" + "border-color: " + boxSetup[i][1] + ";' onclick='" + onclick + "'>" + boxSetup[i][0] + "</label></br />\n";
    }
  }

  if (waifu[0] != "") {
    $('waifu-left').style.display = "block";
    $('waifu-left').src = waifu[0];
  }
  if (waifu[1] != "") {
    $('waifu-right').style.display = "block";
    $('waifu-right').src = waifu[1];
  }
}

function build() {
  var skip = false,
    c = 1,
    r = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i <= links.length - 1; i++) {
    if (links[i][0] == "---" && links[i][1] == "---") {
      skip = true;
      c++;
    }

    if (!skip) {
      if (c == searchBox) {
        // search engines
        var table = $('search');
        var row = table.insertRow(r);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
          cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        cell1.innerHTML = "<label for='search-" + r + "'>" + links[i][0] + "</label>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input id='search-" + r + "' type='text' value='' \
" + "onfocus='javascript:activeInput=true;if(searchBox!=pg) go(searchBox);' onblur='javascript:activeInput=false;' \
" + "onkeypress='javascript:handleKeyPress(event,\"" + links[i][1] + "\",this.value);' />";

        r++;
      } else {
        // links
        var lnk_js = ["", ""];
        if (enableTitle) {
          lnk_js = ["javascript:open(\"", "\");"];
        }
        $('box-' + c).innerHTML += "<a href='" + lnk_js[0] + links[i][1] + lnk_js[1] + "' target='_self'>" + links[i][0] + "</a><br />";
      }
    }

    skip = false;
  }
}

function cleanup() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (pg == searchBox) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++) {
      input[i].style.background = color;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++) {
      input[i].style.background = dimColor;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= boxSetup.length; i++) {
    $('pg-' + i).style.background = "transparent";
  }
  $('pg-' + pg).style.background = color;

  var b = 0,
    c = 0,
    steps = parseInt(rotation.length / 2);
  if (pg >= 2) { // left side
    for (var i = (pg - 1); i >= 1; i--) {
      $('box-' + i).style.cssText = "opacity: " + (parseFloat(dim[c] / 100)) + "; \
" + "margin-left: " + (margins[0][c] + marginC) + "px; margin-top: " + (curve[0][c] + marginT) + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg);";

      if (c < steps - 1) {
        c++;
        b++;
      }
    }
  }

  b = steps;
  c = 0;
  if (pg <= boxSetup.length) { // right side
    for (var i = (pg + 1); i <= boxSetup.length; i++) {
      $('box-' + i).style.cssText = "opacity: " + (parseFloat(dim[c] / 100)) + "; \
" + "margin-left: " + (margins[1][c] + marginC) + "px; margin-top: " + (curve[1][c] + marginT) + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[1][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(" + translateZ[0][c] + "px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[b][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[b][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[b][0] + "deg);";

      if (c < steps - 1) {
        c++;
        b++;
      }
    }
  }
}

function move(p) {
  var c = rotation.length - 1;

  $('box-' + pg).style.cssText = "opacity: 1.0; \
" + "margin-left: " + marginC + "px; margin-top: " + marginT + "px; \
" + "-moz-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(0px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[c][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[c][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[c][0] + "deg); \
" + "-webkit-transform: perspective(" + perspective + "px) translateZ(0px) \
" + "rotateZ(" + rotation[c][2] + "deg) rotateY(" + rotation[c][1] + "deg) rotateX(" + rotation[c][0] + "deg);";

  cleanup();
}

function go(x) { // switch using tags
  if (x != pg) {
    if (x > pg)
      while (x > pg) {
        move(pg++);
      } else
        while (x < pg) {
          move(pg--);
        }
  }
}

function open(url) { // url handler w/ clickable boxes
  var x = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if ((links[i][1] == url && x == pg) || !enableTitle) {
      window.location = url;
    } else if (links[i][1] == url) {
      go(x);
    }

    if (links[i][0] == "---" && links[i][1] == "---") {
      x++;
    }
  }
}

function handleKeyPress(e, url, q) { // query
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which
  if (key == 13) {
    window.location = url + q;
  }
}

var scrollLock = false,
  sl_timer;

function MouseWheelHandler(e) { // scroll navigation
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

  if ((!scrollLock || !useScrollLock) && enableScroll) {
    if (!invertScroll) {
      if (delta == -1 && pg < boxSetup.length) {
        move(pg++);
      } else if (delta == -1 && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
        go(1);
      }
      if (delta == 1 && pg > 1) {
        move(pg--);
      } else if (delta == 1 && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
        go(boxSetup.length);
      }
    } else {
      if (delta == 1 && pg < boxSetup.length) {
        move(pg++);
      } else if (delta == 1 && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
        go(1);
      }
      if (delta == -1 && pg > 1) {
        move(pg--);
      } else if (delta == -1 && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
        go(boxSetup.length);
      }
    }

    if (useScrollLock) {
      scrollLock = true;
      clearTimeout(sl_timer);
      sl_timer = setTimeout("scrollLock=false", scrollLockMS);
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var activeInput = false;
document.onkeydown = function(e) { // key navigation
  if (!activeInput && enableKeys) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which

    if (key >= 49 && (key <= 57 && key <= (48 + boxSetup.length))) {
      go(key - 48);
    } // key 1-9
    if (key >= 97 && (key <= 105 && key <= (96 + boxSetup.length))) {
      go(key - 96);
    } // num key 1-9

    if ((key == 37 || key == 65) && pg > 1) {
      move(pg--);
    } // key left and A
    else if ((key == 37 || key == 65) && pg == 1 && !edgeBlock) {
      go(boxSetup.length);
    }
    if ((key == 39 || key == 68) && pg < boxSetup.length) {
      move(pg++);
    } // key right and D
    else if ((key == 39 || key == 68) && pg == boxSetup.length && !edgeBlock) {
      go(1);
    }
  }
}

function getUsernote() {
  document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = 'Write your note here';
}

getUsernote();
init();
```

```css
/* This is the fix */
#oneout {
    position: relative;
}


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Liberation Sans", "Dejavu Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
#perspective {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
#preset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
a:link {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1.0;
  min-width: 155px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  /* (-5px|5px) link move left or right */
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
a:active {
  color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
input[type="text"]:hover {
  width: 30px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: text;
}
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  /* Vertical Align */
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 1s ease;
  /* Animation speed/time */
}
.container label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*#box-3 { margin-left: -75px; opacity: 1; }*/

/* Selected box */

#search td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
#search label {
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#switch {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#switch:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  cursor: default;
  /* (pointer|default) */
}
#shadow-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#shadow-bot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
  <div id="boxes"></div>
</div>
<div id="switch"></div>

<div id="preset"></div>

<div id="oneout" style="scoped">
  <div id="oneout_inner">
    <div id="note-pad">
      <div id="note" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <center>
      <a class="clear" href=''>Clear</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```